# Where was Luke's Jedi Temple/Academy located?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, jedi-training

In *The Force Awakens* and *The Last Jedi*, it was mentioned that Luke Skywalker took on students and started teaching them the ways of the Force before Kylo Ren killed them all and left Luke for dead. Specifically in *The Last Jedi*, [we see a few shots of the place where this happened](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_Luke_Skywalker%27s_Jedi_Temple?file=Jedi_massacre_TLJ.png). It looks like some sort of Jedi Temple.

The thing is, I don't know where all this happened, and I can't find any information on it. I know in Legends, Luke rebuilt the Jedi Order on Yavin 4; is there any indication of where this training was going on in the new canon?

Comment: It was on Acht-To that was where the first Jedi temple was, and where Luke was at. I know that isn't what you are asking, but it still could be useful.

Comment: @DarthVader Where has it ever been said the Academy was on Ahch-to?

Comment: @Machavity - It's in the starwars wikia somewhere, but I think it was part of the story discarded when JJ Abrams took over.

Comment: @JohnP I mean stated in canon. I know Lucas wanted it to be there. Darth's comment implies it's a known fact

Comment: @Machavity - Here it is: *During the early development of The Force Awakens, one of the many ideas that George Lucas originally envisioned for the Star Wars sequel trilogy involved Luke training his new disciple Kira (renamed Rey in the finished version of the film) at a Jedi Temple located at the planet which ultimately became Ahch-To....The idea was discarded after J.J. Abrams entered to direct the film* [Linky](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker%27s_Jedi_Temple) - As far as canon, I don't think it is stated.

Comment: @Machavity - Unless he means that is where the *FIRST* Temple was, not necessarily *Luke's* temple.

Comment: The video game "Star Wars: Jedi Academy" has look teaching at a Jedi academy on Yavin 4. It doesn't fit canonically though I think since students graduate from it without Kylo Ren killing them.

Comment: @BenWaters - That's based on some of the Legends/EU books, in those books his academy was on Yavin 4.

Comment: @DarthVader I'm definitely not talking about Ahch-To, I'm talking about where Luke trained his students before Kylo killed them all. He 'trained' Rey on Ahch-To, but if it was the same place that he trained Ben then the First Order would've had no trouble finding him.

Comment: @JohnP Yes. I mean where the FIRST temple was.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Then you are out of luck. I don't have any idea where that temple was.

Answer (score 3):

There's no indications where the scenes we've only gotten bits and pieces of in TFA and TLJ actually happened. While George Lucas wanted it to be Ahch-to, it seems unlikely Luke would hide on a planet Kylo Ren knows. Furthermore, Leia would also likely have searched the ruins of the Academy for her brother.

Another strike against the Ahch-to is that [Ahch-to appears to have only one moon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahch-To) (per the [Junior Novelization](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)), while the Temple had at least 2

[image]

It's possible Episode IX will tell us definitively, but no canon sources have to date.

Comment: Just so you know, I was stating that Luke was just hiding out on Acht-To and that it was also the location of (one of) the first Jedi temple. I was not saying that it was where he trained the new Jedi.